# Redirect 301 issue Apache behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

My non-www `example.com` has been redirected to `www.example.com/index.php`.

Note: I'm redirecting using `.htaccess` and not with nginx virtual host file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If I comment the lines in `.htaccess` and try to redirect through nginx virtual host file curl respond correctly as set but I received a 404 (model by my site) when access `www.example.com`.

By the way, is it better to redirect this through `.htaccess` or nginx? As I'm using nginx as proxy.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;



location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

Virtual Host code Nginx

```
server {
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

curl -I example.com

 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Date: Mon, 04 Dec 2017 20:39:54 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html
 Connection: keep-alive
 Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d7048cb8bebb2c847d904c46cd78d8f0c1512419; 
 expires=Tue, 04-Dec-18 20:39:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
 Location: http://www.example.com/
 Server: cloudflare-nginx
 CF-RAY: 3c8193e88245-EWR
```

All site is working fine but just at the index I receive a 403 Forbidden.
Note: it's a internal redirect so I don't know which one nginx or apache is better for performance. In apache non-www is redirect to www.example.com/index.php (I don't want this .index.php and in nginx is redirected normally but I receive a 403 at homepage with the rest of the site working fine.

Comment: Please show the "redirect through nginx virtual host file" and the corresponding HTTP response headers. If this is an _external redirect_ then there should be no difference to the `.htaccess` approach. (Except that doing this redirect in Nginx virtual host - at the proxy level - would indeed be the preferred option in terms of performance.)

Comment: I edited my question and put the information asked. Thanks!

Comment: If Apache is redirecting to `index.php` then it maybe that you've put the redirect in the wrong place? Do you have other directives? Otherwise, the `.htaccess` code you posted would only redirect to `index.php` if `index.php` was on the original request. "it's a internal redirect" - what do you mean? A 3xx response is an _external redirect_. This needs to be an _external redirect_, as it needs to redirect the _client_ to `www` (your server may not even care).

Comment: Ok, let's forget apache and focus on nginx. Why when I use redirect 301 through virtual host the site works fine but at the home of the site I receive a 403 Forbidden?

Comment: but answering your question, yes  `htaccess` is corret because when I use just apache the non-www redirect to www. without the index.php

Comment: I'm sure the problem of everything is on the config of the virtual host file.

Comment: I founded that when I put the 301 redirect on nginx virtual file the www.example.com get the "default" virtual host which is set to /var/www/ but the other pages for example: www.example.com/testes/ works fine.

Comment: Problem solved. I was putting the redirect inside the same block "server { }" and you have to put in a separete block server.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. You can add that as an "answer" (and accept it). That way it will benefit other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was putting the redirect inside the same `server {}` block and I needed to put in a separate `server {}` block just for the `example.com` host.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```